# Transforming equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does $\;y = 2e^{3x} - 2e^{-3x} - 5e^{-3x}\;$ turn into $\quad y = 4\left(\dfrac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{2}\right) - 5e^{-3x}\;$?

Specifically how does $$2e^{3x} - 2e^{-3x} = 4\left(\frac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{2}\right)\quad ?$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be making the problem more complicated than it really is. For example, if you "work backwards":

$$4\left(\frac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{2}\right) = 2\left(e^{3x} -e^{-3x}\right) = 2e^{3x} - 2e^{-3x} $$

We simply *simplified* the fraction $4/2  = 2$ and multiplied through by $2$ (distributive rule).

So if we reverse directions and start from $\;\displaystyle (2e^{3x} - 2e^{-3x}) ,\;$ we essentially *factor out* $4$ from each term:

$$2e^{3x} - 2e^{-3x} = 2\left(e^{3x} - e^{-3x}\right) = \left(\frac{4\cdot \left(e^{3x} - e^{-3x}\right)}{2}\right) = 4\left(\frac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{2}\right)$$